# backslash (\) position in nftables grammar

Tags: nftables

As the webpage describe:
[nftables guide](https://linux-audit.com/nftables-beginners-guide-to-traffic-filtering/)

```
; = more commands or parameters to follow
\ = break a rule into multiple lines
```

For the command :

```
nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 \; policy accept\; }
```

I read it as

```
nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { 
          type filter hook output priority 0 ; 
          policy accept ; 
}
```

What puzzle me is the position of `\`,why not put it behind `:` to break lines such as :

```
nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}
```

?

Answer (score 2):

This is not related to *nftables* grammar but to POSIX shell grammar: the `;` must be escaped or the shell will consider there is a separator and a new shell command is following.

This expression running in a shell:

```
nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 \; policy accept\; }
```

is equivalent to this expression still in a shell:

```
nft add chain ip traffic-filter output '{ type filter hook output priority 0 ; policy accept; }'
```

or this one among a lot of similar possibilities (since `nft` does its own parameter splitting, the way grouping of parameters is done doesn't really matter):

```
nft 'add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ; policy accept; }'
```

Without escaping *for the shell* this could happen:

```
# nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ; policy accept; }
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

The error comes from `bash` not from `nft`.

---

Any [random non-official documentation](https://linux-audit.com/nftables-beginners-guide-to-traffic-filtering/) can't be trusted blindly. The use of the `\` character is documented in the man page ([`nft(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#LEXICAL_CONVENTIONS)):

> ### LEXICAL CONVENTIONS
>
> Input is parsed line-wise. **When the last character of a line, just
> before the newline character, is a non-quoted backslash (`\`), the next
> line is treated as a continuation**. Multiple commands on the same line
> can be separated using a semicolon (`;`).
>
> A hash sign (`#`) begins a comment. All following characters on the same
> line are ignored.
>
> Identifiers begin with an alphabetic character (`a`-`z`,`A`-`Z`), followed
> zero or more alphanumeric characters (`a`-`z`,`A`-`Z`,`0`-`9`) and the characters
> slash (`/`), **backslash (`\`)**, underscore (`_`) and dot (`.`). Identifiers
> using different characters or clashing with a keyword need to be
> enclosed in double quotes (`"`).

Note how the backslash **(`\`) gets a special meaning only before a newline** (although contrary to the description above and contrary to `/` I didn't find a place where `\` gets freely accepted). If you don't want any problem, **always single quote (`'`) commands** to prevent shell interaction, and inside do as you see fit. But note that inside these single quotes a backslash followed by a space will be seen as *two* normal characters by the `nft` command.

So you have a few choices:

- use `\` + *newline* to split a single command over multiple lines
- use `;` to join multiple commands (or parts of command with such syntax) on a single line.
- replace a `;` by a *newline* to split two joined commands
- When interactive rather than in a script you can opt to use `nft -i` to type an interactive command to avoid shell interaction and thus not require special attention to avoid interactions of '' or ';' with the shell, so you can see how it's working.
- anyway once a ruleset is made, better store it in a file and manipulate the ruleset with `nft -f`.

So OP's 2nd example could be written like this (still running from a shell):

```
nft 'add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0;\
policy accept;\
}
'
```

But then both the `;` and the line join get useless and this can become simply:

```
nft 'add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0
policy accept
}
'
```

The notation below is invalid, because the backslash isn't immediately followed by a newline:

```
nft 'add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}'
```

`nft` version 0.9.8 issues these multiple errors for above:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected junk
add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}
                                                                         ^
Error: syntax error, unexpected junk
add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}
                                                                                           ^
Error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}
^
```

Comment: Why can't write it as `nft add chain ip traffic-filter output { type filter hook output priority 0 ;\ policy accept ; \}`?

Comment: I added a more detailed explanation about your example. Be careful to not confuse bash and nft escapes and don't get tangled in their interactions.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's nitpicking, but that "is equivalent to this expression still in a shell" sounds a bit off, since _in the shell_ those are different, even if they're interpreted the same by `nft`. (I'm partly looking against the N+1 shell questions here on the site, where the difference in the shell between things like those two ends up being exactly the point.)

Comment: @ilkkachu That's because of the presence of the single quotes. For example one can't add a single quote in a comment without knowing it's running from a shell, so one must always bear in mind it's in a shell.  (yet-an-other-edit) Interactive usage without shell is possible: using `nft -i` instead.